# Blazor Server side - Modify model values from a control panel

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor calculator that uses some inputs compares them to some system variables and shows the result.

I use a model with both Input variables and system variables:

(Example)

Input variables that i get and bind using:

```
<InputText style="width: 100%" @bind-Value="model.vrefavg" class="form-control">
</InputText>

public double vrefavg { get; set; }
```

System variables then i compare with inputs:

```
if (model.vrefavg > model.dieselgasoilcf) {
model.Final=2000;
}

public double Dieselgasoilcf { get; set; } = 3.206;
public double lightfueloilcf { get; set; } = 3.151;
public double heavyfueloilcf { get; set; } = 3.114;
```

This System variables will need to change with the next few years, thus i want to be able to change them through a Login-> Admin Panel page i have created without having to edit the source code and reupload.

I have noticed that i can only @bind-value on the Index page, and i assume even if i work arround that, each time the application reloads the system variables will be set into their initial value that is on my model.

Any ideas on how tot do this?

Please note, first app ever.

Comment: You can load them from wherever you're persisting them in e.g. OnInitialized or OnAfterRender (but maybe only if firstRender is true if you do use that)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to explain. what do you mean by persisting them?

Comment: Normally for data that changes between successive executions of code, we save it somewhere; a DB, a file -> persisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to put something like this in your page:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if(!File.Exists("fuels.txt"))
      File.WriteAllText("fuels.txt", "3.206\r\n3.151\r\n3.114");

    var f = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync("fuels.txt");
    Dieselgasoilcf = double.Parse(f[0]);
    Lightfueloilcf = double.Parse(f[1]);
    Heavyfueloilcf = double.Parse(f[2]);
}
```

..then when the page is initing, the file would be read and the first 3 lines (the file would hence be `3.206\r\n3.151\r\n3.114`) would be used to give values to the page variables

Presumably another page somewhere would set the values and write a new file..

The file is just an example; database would also be typical, but I wanted something quick and easy to demo the point - it's not about the file per se, it's about the notion that you store your data somewhere not baked into the code of the app, you read it in from that place, and assign it to your in-app variables, you use them, maybe you have some process that updates the file, the app quits, the app loads again tomorrow, the data is remembered..

That data can be anywhere sensible, outside the app; environment variables, an API call, a file, a database..

Comment: I understand the theory you have explained but unfortunately, this is my first time programming. I will try to find how to read that values from a file as you have mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't let it put you off :) The hardest thing would perhaps be figuring out where to put the file. You can cheat; i modified the code to place a file for you if it's not there already - it'll end up somewhere on disk!

Comment: I am starting to look into DB since it will also help me in other sections. Is Blazor CRUD what I should be looking for? I belive this will solve the problem right?

Comment: It's not something I've heard of as "a thing", but I know what Blazor is and what CRUD refers to.. The simple solution for using a DB in Blazor would perhaps be to put a SQLServer DB somewhere, install EF Core Power Tools, Get EFCPT to reverse engineer the DB and then put code in your app that uses it. Be careful though; you can easily use EFCore wrongly in Blazor  - see [Microsoft's advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Simplest for now; make a new context when you need it rather than using dependency injection

Comment: Looked at the first thing I found for Blazor CRUD .. Mmm, it's what I thought it'd be, and it's not as simple as the approach commented above; Blazor Server is server side, with a SignalR connection from client browser to server. It's thus a bit of a nonsense to write another app(API) that is a server side app that the server side blazor connects to as a client - you end up generating a server side app that connects to another server side app, and that another app's job is to front up a database, which involves a boatload of data manipulation that isn't really necessary here.

Comment: It's application layers for the sake of application layers: `browser <-> blazor server <-> server api <-> server db` and it's very tedious (I'm actively doing it right now, in VS in front of me, because I also have non-blazorserver clients that use the same API, but if I was rapid prototyping, I wouldn't do it - i'd just put EFCore straight into Blazor and then have `browser <-> blazorserver <-> db`)

Comment: Understood. I will avoid CRUD and work on browser <-> blazorserver <-> db.

Comment: It'll come in handy one day, and BlazorWASM apps will make better use of it, because they're `browser-with-blazor-app <-> api <-> db`, but Blazor Server allows you some nice shortcut there because it, conceptually, is like a remote control of an app that runs on the server - secrets like your db connection string and cool algorithms don't leave the server - the only thing that leaves the server is a stream of HTML diffs that are patched into the document in the browser to give the illusion of an app. It means your server side can directly use the DB; it's like an API in itself

Comment: I have managed to create a SQLite data base with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPZVMw4i_Qw&ab_channel=TechnicalBundle

But i don't know how to use the values on my Index page similarly how i would use a model value: (Example)

 if (model.SixthAuxilaryEnginetechnicalfileAvailable == "No")
        {
            model.SixthAuxilaryEngineSfc = 14;

        }

I mean how do I use the Class products on my Index page?

Comment: It's hard to know where you've gotten up to just off a comment. Perhaps post the code you have now,up as a new question - feel free to link me to it. In essence, you ought to have done something like: made a db, made a table called FuelSettings with column names of Name and Value, put data in it such that Name="diesel" and Value=3.206, and made an instance of the context and queried it for data, so doing e.g. `var context = new YourContext();` `Dieselgasoilcf = context.FuelSettings.First(fs fs.Name == "diesel").Value;` in your OnInit.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done, But did not rename much so I don't mess up things :) I will post everything and tag you in. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71691803/18036541

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project `appsettings.json` for such information.  You can't update the values through a "Control Panel", but you make a simple change to the site configuration file.  If you want some sort of control panel then you need to persist the data in a datastore (Database or File somewhere).

Here's the appsettings setup if you want to use it:

Add a section to `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "FuelCoefficients": {
    "Dieselgasoilcf": 3.206,
    "Lightfueloilcf": 3.151,
    "Heavyfueloilcf": 3.114
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Create a class to read the data into:

```
public class FuelCoefficients
{
    public const string SectionName = "FuelCoefficients";

    public double Dieselgasoilcf { get; set; }
    public double Lightfueloilcf { get; set; }
    public double Heavyfueloilcf { get; set; }
}
```

Add a section to `Program` to load the data

```
builder.Services.Configure<FuelCoefficients>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(FuelCoefficients.SectionName));
```

Use it wherever in your application through Dependancy Injection like this:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<FuelCoefficients> fuelCoefficients

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div>
    Diesel Value: @this.fuelCoefficients.Value.Dieselgasoilcf<br />
    Light Value: @this.fuelCoefficients.Value.Lightfueloilcf<br />
    Heavy Value: @this.fuelCoefficients.Value.Heavyfueloilcf<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your information, I need to have that control panel option thus I just started looking into databases. Do you know any source that can guide me with a similar example on how to create a database for this? Is Blazr CRUD what I am looking for?

Comment: It all depends on 1. How much data are you going to store in your database? 2. How are you deploying your application.  If it's fairly simple you can use SQLite.  Search the Internet for "Deploy SQLLite in Blazor".  There are various good article and YouTube tutorials.

Comment: 1. How much data are you going to store in your database? Around 50 values maximum. (diesel=10.5, petrol=17,5 etc etc)
2. How are you deploying your application. I was thinking of Azure but didn't come to that stage yet.
I will research on SQLlite in Blazor

Comment: Then use SQLite and one of the tutorials for getting started.